# How much ram can I put in ASUS X302LJ-FN027H?

Tags: memory, upgrade, asus-laptop

How much ram can I put in ASUS X302LJ-FN027H? And how many slots does it have? Belarc Computer Advisor and my Task Manager says it has 2 slots, but crucial says it has only 1, so I am a bit confused.

i3-5010
4gb ram
2gb dedicated graphics

Comment: Have you looked at the manual?

Comment: it says nothing :(

Comment: I bet it does.  It sounds like there is a single user accessible module.  So you are limited to 4GB modules for that reason

Comment: Does that mean I have two slots for 4 gigs of RAM? I am confused whether I buy an 8gb or a 4gb.

Comment: Sounds like you have one slot for RAM.  If you wanted to upgrade you'd have to buy an 8GB to swap out with your 4GB.  Even there website, when it finally loaded was sparse with knowledge about it.  It is DDR3 1600, but no mention of max memory supported.

Comment: The manual indicates how replace the module.  I suggest you follow those steps to manually inspect it.  I literally said you have one module, the other module if your machine has one, likely isn't serviceable.  Manual is very specific, you have a single user serviceable module.

Comment: So if I manually inspect my slots and I have another one, which one should I buy, 4gb or 8gb? I plan to buy in Amazon.

Comment: You didn't indicate what CPU you have in your system.  If I were to hazard a highly educated guess, your systems will only accept 4GB modules.  I mean the [5500U](http://ark.intel.com/products/85214/Intel-Core-i7-5500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz) only supports 16GB in total with only 2 channels.  Which means the high-end option only supports 8GB modules.  The fact the laptop only came with 4GB modules tells me what it supports. [This](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/x302lj) supports the 4GB module limit.

Comment: [Contact Asus support and ask them](https://vip.asus.com/VIP2/Services/QuestionForm?lang=en-us)

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can replace your **1** stick of 4gb RAM with identical DDR3L 1600 MHz 8GB stick. Worked Great for me, really improves the performance.